# getting "SyntaxError" when installing twilio in the Windows command line interface

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new here and also a new Python learner. I was trying to install twilio package through the Windows command line interface, but I got a syntax error(please see below). I know there're related posts, however, I was still unable to make it work after trying those solutions. Perhaps I need to set the path in the command line, but I really have no idea how to do that...(I can see the easy_install and pip files in the Scripts folder under Python) Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>python Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015,
>   09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi n32 Type "help",
>   "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > > easy_install twilio   File "", line 1
> > > >             easy_install twilio
> > > >                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 6):

You need to navigate to c:\python27\scripts and then run the command

```
easy_install twilio
```

this link helps too:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/udacity-hosted-downloads/ud036/How+to+install+Twilio+on+Windows.pdf

Comment: Thanks Seif! I was able to did it successfully yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

You should not type python first, then it becomes python command line.
Open a new command prompt and directly type: 
easy_install twilio

Answer (score 1):

go to the command prompt 
it will say the account and all that jazz.
type cd .. 
then hit enter
it will say C:\Users>
type cd .. again
then it will say C:>
type cd python27 (or the name of your python folder)
it will say C:\Python27>
type cd scripts
it will say C:\python27/scripts>
type easy_install twilio

then wait for it to run the procceses and then you will have twilio installed to python.